# write rows instead of columns in google spreadsheet function

Tags: google-apps-script

I call a function from a spreadsheet cell. In this function I am computing an array and I would like to write the array components as sequential cells in the row of the spreadsheet.

So far my function does almost what I need, as it writes the array components as sequential cells in the *column*, how do I get it to write along the row instead?

My function writes simply by return, that is

```
function name() { 

//something that computes "results"

var flname = result.split(",")

return flname;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to change the return into
    `return [flname];`